How to detect finished migration from neo4j 3.5 to 4.4
I want to automate the process of upgrading Neo4j from version 3.5 to version 5.20 using purposefully built docker containers.
My current process is:
Using 3.5-dump container I have backed up my 3.5 using neo4j-admin dump.
Then using another container with Neo4j 4.4 I loaded the dump with neo4j-admin load.
It reports:
"The loaded database is not on the latest format (current:v0.A.9, latest:SF4.3.0). Set dbms.allow_upgrade=true to enable migration."
Now, I can start the database and it will perform the data migration, but how can I detect it is finished?
I want to chain another dump and load it into 5.20 into a single script.
Right now, I would have to check the progress manually.
Is there a way to start the neo4j to perform the initial load/migration and exit?
